# Stored Procedure running for multiple days.... is there something wrong with my syntax that's causing it to loop indefinitely?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a stored procedure that is looping through a cursor until no more entries are found. Based off the data structure that i am given, it is pulling all 'hourly timestamps' that have not been used in a SUM calculation yet. These calculations are done by inserting these 'hourly timestamps' as an input parameter in the where clause of the sub procedures (i.e. **PROC1**). When I do a count(*) from the cursor, i get ~157,000 entries (which means i should only have a million entries TOPS). More than 2 days for a million entries seems incorrect. Is there anything in my code that I may have missed that may be causing this to happen? (Below is a simplified version of my code)

Thanks in advance.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE RUN_AGG
is
 v_Flag_id NUMBER;
  CURSOR hours IS
    SELECT distinct(HR) as RHR
    , submission_value_id
    from (
    select  
        v.DATA_DATE,
        v.HR,
        sv.submission_value_id
     from value v
     inner join submission_value sv on sv.value_id = v.value_id
     where sv.SUBMISSION_VALUE_ID NOT IN (
     SELECT SUBMISSION_VALUE_ID FROM VALUE_FLAG WHERE VALUE_FLAG.FLAG_ID =   (SELECT FLAG_ID from FLAG where FLAG_TX = 'Processed'))
  ));
l_hr hours%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT FLAG_ID into v_flag_id from FLAG where FLAG_TX = 'Processed';
OPEN hours;
 LOOP 
    FETCH hours into l_hr;
    EXIT WHEN hours%NOTFOUND;
      PROC1(l_hr.RHR);
      PROC2(l_hr.RHR);
      PROC3(l_hr.RHR);
      PROC4(l_hr.RHR);
      PROC5(l_hr.RHR);
      insert into value_flag (value_flag_id, submission_value_id, value_flag_type_id)
                      values (null, l_hr.submission_value_id, (select value_flag_type_id from value_flag_type where value_flag_tx = 'AGG_HOURLY'));
END LOOP;
CLOSE hours;
```

Not sure if relevant or if it would help, but the 5 'sub procs' are procedures that sum up by Hour based on different filtering /where criteria. Below is an example of what each of these procs look like:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROC1(rHR IN TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) 
is
CURSOR c1 is
select  SUM(v.value_tx)as sum_of_values
      , v.data_Code
      , v.region_id
      , v.hr
      , ABS(tz.TIME_ZONE_OFFSET) as utc_offset
  from value v
  inner join submission_value sv on v.value_id = sv.value_id
  inner join region r on r.REGION_ID = v.REGION_ID
  left join time_zone tz on r.TIME_ZONE_ID = tz.TIME_ZONE_ID
 where ff.form_field_tx in ('SAMPLE', 'NO')
   and sv.submission_value_id in (
    select
        distinct(max(sv_all.submission_value_id) over (partition by v9.auth_code, v9.data_date, form_field_id, v9.data_code, v9.hr)) max_svid 
    from submission_value sv_all 
        inner join value v9 on v9.value_id = sv_all.value_id
        where v9.HR = rHR
        )   
   and v.HR = rHR
group by v.region_id, ff.form_field_id, ff.form_field_tx, v.hr, v.data_code, ABS(tz.TIME_ZONE_OFFSET);
  l_var c1%ROWTYPE;
  v_value_id value.value_id%type;
BEGIN
Open c1;
     FETCH c1 into l_var;
              insert into calculation (calculation_id, calculation_date, calculation_name, report_period_dt)
                               values (null, sysdate, 'AGG_HR_REG ' || trunc(rHR) || ' ' || to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss'), trunc(l_var.hr))
Close c1;
Open c1;
LOOP
     FETCH c1 into l_var;
     EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
          insert into value (value_id, energy_product_id, data_source_id, unit_cd, value_tx, utc_offset, data_date, hr_utc, hr, hr_num, data_code)
                         values (null, '1', '2', 'NA', l_var.sum_of_values, l_var.utc_offset, null, null, l_var.hr, null, l_var.data_code)
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE c1;
commit;
END PROC1;
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You need to divide and conquer with optimization. Run each query/subquery by itself and see if you can identify the bottleneck. If all the queries run quickly only then do you need to think about refactoring the cursor logic.

Comment: Are you sure *all* of the cursor loops in all the sub-procs have an `exit` condition? You might find this easier if you used implicit  cursor loops instead of the explicit open/loop/fetch pattern. And have you ruled out another session with uncommitted changes blocking the inserts you are trying to do?

Comment: @Error_2646 thank you, i will do that. Thank you

Comment: @AlexPoole yes, i went back and checked and they do. I will look into implicit cursor loops as I am not very familiar with them. Also, I have committed all changes prior to running this stored procedure. Thanks by the way!

Comment: `More than 2 days for a million entries seems incorrect.` - it depends how long each procedure takes. Assuming that one procedure takes an average of 200ms, multiply by 5 times (5 procedures), multiply by 157.000 records, then the whole process will take 43 hours. But if each procedure takes 1000ms instead of 200ms, then the whole process will take 215 hours (9 days). Did you profile your code and measure times ?

Comment: How well does the main `hours` cursor perform on its own? Is `value_flag.submission_value_id` nullable? (`not in` subqueries with nullable keys can be a problem.) Does it help if you replace `value_flag.flag_id = (subquery)` with `value_flag.flag_id = v_flag_id`? The lookup of `value_flag_type` in the `insert` is repeated for each row, but it looks like you could save the value in a variable at the start, similar to `v_flag_id`. If you can set up a test of a small set that runs in a reasonable time, profile it to see where the time goes.

Comment: If you instrumented your code, say using `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO`, you would not need to ask _us_ what your code is doing, you would be able to ask the Oracle database.